# About the interior of the union of two sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $A,B\subseteq X.$ We know that in general, we only have
$$\operatorname{int}(A)\cup\operatorname{int}(B)\subseteq\operatorname{int}(A\cup B). $$

My question is: When do we say that equality holds?

I came with this idea because if there was such condition for which the equality holds, then I can manage to prove that
$$\partial (A\cup B)=\partial A\cup \partial B$$
whenever $\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}=\varnothing.$

Any tips?:)

Comment: For sure, it holds if $A,B$ are open sets.

Comment: @Sigur Ahh...thanks If $A,B$ are open then we get $$int(A\cup B)=A\cup B=int(A)\cup int(B).$$

Comment: What is $b$? ..

Comment: @M.B $b$ stands for boundary

Comment: I think that if $\partial A\cap\partial B=\emptyset$ then the equality holds.

Comment: @Tomas. Thanks for the suggestion. I have to verify it on my own(If I can do it.:))

Comment: @jun, yes, you can. Just don't forget the definitions, you can not prove something if you don't know with what you are working.

Comment: @Sigur. Are you referring to the comment of Tomas or to your previous comment?:)

Comment: @jun, your last comment.

Comment: @Sigur. :)Thanks. I'm still doing the suggested comment.

Comment: @Tomas. I really like your suggestion.Nice!! If we assume that $\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}=\varnothing$, then I get $$\partial A \cap \partial B=\varnothing$$

Comment: What if interiors of A and B are empty?

Comment: @Ram If interiors of A and B are empty, then $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B} = \varnothing$ trivially.

Comment: @tetori What if A=B?

Comment: @Ram oh.... my mistake.

Comment: @tetori. That's not entirely true. Consider rationals of the unit interval as $A$ and irrationals of the unit interval as $B$. Then both have empty interioirs, the sets are disjoint, but $\bar{A}=\bar{B}$.

Comment: A nontrivial sufficient condition is for $A$ and $int(B)$ to each be closed sets.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Claim:

$ int(A\cup B) = int(A) \cup int(B) \iff \partial A \cap \partial B \subset \partial (A \cup B) $

Proof:

Since you are more intrested in the ($\Leftarrow$) part of the claim I will first prove that. For both parts of the proof, remeber that interior, exterior and boundary of a set is a partitioning of the whole space i.e. $int(A) \cup \partial A \cup ext(A) = X$ where all three sets are **disjoint**. Also, interior and exterior are open sets.

($\Leftarrow$)
As you have said $int(A) \cup int(B) \subset int(A\cup B)$. So, I will only focus on proving $int(A\cup B) \subset int(A) \cup int(B)$.

Let $x \in int (A \cup B)$. If $x \in int(A)$ or $x \in int(B)$ then we are done. So, assume that $x \notin int(A)$ and $x \notin int(B)$.

By hypothesis, if $x \in \partial A \cap \partial B$ then $x \in \partial(A\cup B)$ but interior and boundary of $(A \cup B)$ are disjoint which is a contradiction. So, $x \notin \partial A \cap \partial B$.

Without loss of generality, assume that $x \notin \partial B$. Then, $x \in ext(B)$ and either $x \in \partial A$ or $x \in ext(A)$.

Case 1: $x \in \partial A$,

Since $x \in ext(B)$, there is a neighborhood $V \subset B^C$ of x. Since $x \in int(A \cup B)$ there is a neighborhood $U \subset (A\cup B)$ of x. Then,
$U \cap V$ is a neighborhood of $x$ in $X$. Note that $(U \cap V) \subset (A\cup B) \cap B^C \subset A$. But since $x \in \partial A$, any neighborhood of $x$ must intersect non-trivially with $A^C$. Hence, it is a contradiction. So, $x \notin \partial A$.

Case 2: $x \in ext(A)$,

$x \in int(A \cup B) \subset A \cup B \subset \bar A \cup \bar B = (int(A) \cup
\partial A) \cup (int(B) \cup \partial B)$. However $x \in ext(A)$ and $x \in ext(B)$ implying that $x \notin int(A) \cup \partial A$ and
$x \notin int(B) \cup \partial B$ which is a contradiction.

Therefore, $x \in int(A)$ or $x \in int(B)$ i.e. $x \in int(A) \cup int (B)$.

$ (\Rightarrow) $ Let $x \in \partial A \cap \partial B$.

So, $x \notin int(A) $ and $ x \notin int(B)$ implying $x \notin int(A) \cup int(B) = int(A\cup B)$.

Thus, $x \in \partial (A \cup B) \cup ext(A\cup B)$.

Assume $x \in ext(A \cup B)$ then there is a neighborhood $P \subset (A \cup B)^C $ of $x$ (where $A^C$ means the complement for set $A$).

But $(A \cup B)^C \subset A^C$. That is, we have a neighborhood of $x$ which is contained in $A^C$ meaning $ x \notin \partial A$ which is a contradiction.

Hence, $x \in \partial(A\cup B)$.

Comment: Thanks. You have done too much to this problem.

Comment: I enjoyed it and it was a nice exercise to find out such a relation.

Comment: This result eventually got published: https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Some-Properties-of-Interior-and-Closure-in-General-Jung-Nam/4adeb84b3846102e7115716aec8aa0d3d4b2b5d5