# Boundary of the intersection of two open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

Let $A,B$ be open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Does the following equality hold?

$$\partial(A\cap B)= (\bar A \cap \partial B) \cup (\partial A \cap \bar B)$$

Edit: Thanks for showing me in the answers that above formula fails if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint but their boundaries still intersect. I was able to come up with a similar formula which avoids this case
$$[\partial(A\cap B)]\setminus(\partial A \cap \partial B)= (A \cap \partial B) \cup (\partial A \cap B),$$
which I was able to prove and suffices for what I need to do.

However, when showing that $ (A \cap \partial B) \cup (\partial A \cap B)\subseteq \partial(A\cap B)$, I needed to assume that the topology is induced by a metric. I wonder if the formula still holds in an arbitrary topological space.

Comment: Is the boundary defined as $\overline{A}\setminus A$?

Comment: As usual with equalities between sets, the most straight-forward way is to check that each set is a subset of the other. There might be other, cleverer methods out there, but this one, at least, will not fail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not hold. Consider for example $$A=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:|x|<1\}$$ and 
$$B=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:|x-(2,0,\dots,0)|<1\}.$$
Since $A\cap B=\varnothing$, $\partial(A\cap B)=\varnothing$, but the RHS in your formula is the set $\{(1,0,\dots,0)\}$.

Comment: Your example uses tow disjoint sets whose boundaries still intersect. It seems that this is  only case when the formula does not hold. Please check the updated question.

Answer (score 7):

This is not true generally unless $\overline{A\cap B}=\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}$.
\begin{align}
\partial (A\cap B)&= \overline{A\cap B}-(A\cap B)^{o}
\\
&=(\overline{A}\cap \overline{B})-(A^{o}\cap B^{o})
\\
&=(\overline{A}\cap \overline{B})\cap(A^{o}\cap B^{o})^c
\\
&=(\overline{A}\cap \overline{B})\cap(A^{o^c}\cup B^{o^c})
\\
&=(\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}\cap A^{o^c})\cup(\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}\cap B^{o^c})
\\
&=(\overline{A}\cap \partial B)\cup (\overline{B}\cap \partial A)
\end{align}
By [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356758/when-is-the-closure-of-an-intersection-equal-to-the-intersection-of-closures), $\overline{A\cap B}=\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}$ implies discrete space. So this is impossible in $\Bbb{R}^n$. However, we can prove generally 
$$
\partial(A\cap B)\subset (\bar A \cap \partial B) \cup (\partial A \cap \bar B)
$$
for it is always true that $\overline{A\cap B}\subset \overline{A}\cap \overline{B}$. This can be done easily by replacing "$=$" with "$\subset $" at 2nd line of above proof and rest follows.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is dense and co-dense in the non-empty space $X$ (that is, $X$ \ $A$ is also  dense in $X$), suppose $B=X$ \ $A.$ Then $\emptyset=A\cap B=\partial (A\cap B)$ but $\bar A=\bar B=\partial A=\partial B=X\ne \emptyset.$

For example, with $X= \mathbb R^n$ let $A$ be the set of points with rational co-ordinates.