# Formula for the Boundary of an intersection

Tags: general-topology

I'm wondering if there's a formula for $\partial(A\cap B)$. This isn't homework, just wondering.

Comment: Problems arise because in general $\overline{A\cap B}\ne \overline A\cap \overline B$

Comment: This question is likely to be closed for lack of context.  Can you describe the sort of problems that started you wondering about this?

Answer (score 2):

For what it is worth.

$\partial A \cup \partial B = \partial (A\cup B) \cup \partial 
(A\cap B) \cup (\partial A \cap \partial B)$

Answer (score 0):

There is one indeed, but it's a bit clunky unless $\partial{A} \cap \partial{B}=\varnothing$ and $A$ and $B$ are closed. The case for abritrary open sets in an arbitrary space appears [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2031699/boundary-of-the-intersection-of-two-open-sets-in-mathbbrn?rq=1).

A similar identity holds for the boundary of a Cartesian product, whose striking similarity to a product rule is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/939599/is-the-product-rule-for-the-boundary-of-a-cartesian-product-of-closed-sets-an).