# The Intersection of Two Closure Sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $A,B$ be subsets of space $X$.

I know that $\text{Cl}(A\cap B)\subseteq \text{Cl}(A)\cap \text{Cl}(B)$, but under which condition does $\text{Cl}(A)\cap \text{Cl}(B)\subseteq \text{Cl}(A\cap B)$?

Thanks

Comment: The question is too vague. For example, a simple condition is that $A=\emptyset$.

Comment: Thanks, i knew about empty sets. But is there any special space make that come true?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356758/when-is-the-closure-of-an-intersection-equal-to-the-intersection-of-closures). For this condition to happen, we need a discrete topology.

Comment: It's not clear whether the OP is asking for conditions on the soace $X$, or conditions on the sets $A$ and $B$.