# If $U$ is a neighborhood in $D$ of $x$ and $D$ is dense, then the closure in $X$ of $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$ in $X$

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \tau )$ a topological space and $D$ a dense subset. Prove that if
$x\in D$ and $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$ in $D$ (for the subspace topology) then the closure
of $U$ in $X$ is a neighborhood of $x$ in $X$.

My attempt is the following:

I want to show that $\overline{U}$ contains an open neighborhood of x in X.

Let $U$ a neighborhood of $x$ in $D$. Then, exists $U'$ open in $D$ such that $U'\subseteq U$. By definition of subspace topology, exists $V$ an open set in $X$ such that $x\in V$ and $U'=V\cap D$.

I obtain that
$V\cap D=U'\subseteq \overline{U'}^X=\overline{V\cap D}^X=\overline{V}^X\cap \overline{D}^X=\overline{V}^X\cap X=\overline{V}^X$.

So, $U'\subseteq U \Longrightarrow V\subseteq \overline{V}^X=\overline{U'}^X\subseteq \overline{U}^X$.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356758)

Comment: Thanks, I noticed my mistake. Do you have any hints to help me?

Comment: My proof doesn't work at all without that passage.

Comment: Yes, in some ways. But, is it true that $\overline{U}=\overline{U\cap A}$ under these hypothesis?

Comment: Yes it is, see my last comment to the answer [below](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4822973/timeline#comment_10265748). So, the linked post completely answers you question, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Strictly speaking, your proof is correct. But your $\overline{V\cap D}^X=\overline{V}^X\cap \overline{D}^X$, or equivalently (given that $\overline{D}^X=X$)
  $$V\subseteq \overline{V\cap D}^X,$$
  needs some argument, since $\overline{A\cap B}\subseteq\bar A\cap\bar B$ but the reverse inclusion does not hold in general.
- Let us check that $V\subseteq \overline{V\cap D}^X$, i.e. that for any $v\in V$, every open neighborhood $O$ of $v$ (in $X$) meets $V\cap D$. For this, just notice that
  $$O\cap(V\cap D)=(O\cap V)\cap D\ne\varnothing,$$
  since $O\cap V$ is a nonempty open subset of $X$ and $D$ is dense in $X$.
- Note moreover that this "hard part" was sufficient. You can lighten the end of your attempt by just writing:
  $$U'\subseteq U\implies V\subseteq\overline{V\cap D}=\overline{U'}\subseteq\overline U,$$
  and suppressing your previous line of formulas.

Comment: So, is it always true that if $D$ is dense and $V$ is open, $\overline{V\cap D}=\overline{V}$?

Comment: Definitely: the hard part was $V\subseteq\overline{V\cap D}$, which is equivalent to  $\bar V\subseteq\overline{V\cap D}$, and $\bar V\supseteq\overline{V\cap D}$ is obvious

Comment: Ok, so it's enough to prove that $V\subseteq \overline{V\cap D}$ because $\overline{V}$ is the smallest close set that contains $V$ and so $\overline{V}$ is necessarily contained in $\overline{V\cap D}$?

Comment: Indeed! $A\subseteq\bar B\implies\bar A\subseteq\overline{\bar B}=\bar B$.

Comment: Thank you very much!!